# Python different value when printing and reading

Tags: python, postgresql, truncation

I have a stored value in a ".fits" table (there should be no problem with this).
I read the table, and do

```
In [2]: a['RA_touse'][0]
Out[2]: 161.65813
```

This is the real archived value. However, then I do:

```
In [3]: print a['RA_touse'][0]
161.658
```

I get a truncated value. I am using python together with POSTGRES, and this behavior is giving some precision problems.

Could anyone explain this behavior to me, and how to solve it? I need my data to keep in the same format, not change it (i.e., the repr() function would turn everything into strings).

Thanks a lot!

Edit for clarity:

I am using the python script to create a database. What I do is

```
con = psycopg2.connect('todatabase')
cur = con.cursor()
for i in vector_of_something:
    value1 = table['column1'][i]
    value2 = table['column2'][i]
    values = (values1,values2)
    values = [str(value) for value in values]
    command = 'INSERT INTO table values (%s,%s)'
    cur.execute(command,values)
con.commit()
```

The problem is that I get "161.658" in the database as a result, instead of 1.65813.

Comment: What datatypes are you using, both in Python and in the DB?  You'll lose precision trying to work with decimal representations for floating point values.  Also, there's the truncation that happens when a number is formatted for printing, which does not actually reflect a loss of precision of the stored value.

Comment: I am using floats in this case. I have something like:           value = a['RA_touse'][0]                                                 then convert it to string, and the upload it to postgresql

Comment: After your edit.  Why don't you store the values in POSTGRES as Numeric Types, not Strings?

Comment: The database is populated with this script, and then used inversely to get values out of it. Some values are strings (like references), but others are numeric types and have to be kept so, so that python can work properly with them when it gets them from the database.  (or maybe not, I am starting with database manipulation)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a string format with the max amount of decimal points stated.

```
print '%.10f' % a['RA_touse'][0]
```

Comment: If I do that, I get a strange value like 161.6581268311. The problem is that the values are different and have different precisions (they come from different sources), and I want to keep only the recorded value, not a representation. In some cases that will be 4 decimals, in others maybe 6.

Comment: Have you tried `print '%f' % a['RA_touse'][0]` ?

Comment: You are working with floating point numbers.  They are being represented in binary in the system, then converted to/from decimal for i/o.  Base 2 floating point values cannot represent the same exact values as base 10 floating point, so when the values are converted between bases, there's a process of approximation performed.  If you want to keep the exact decimal values, use something like `Decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use floating point values, you have to remember that you are writing them in the code or application interface in base 10 (usually), but they are being stored in base 2.  This is true for integer values as well, but it's not a problem there because all integers can be represented accurately in any base.  Here are some decimal>binary conversion examples to show the problem.

```
dec   bin
.1    .000110011(0011 repeating)
.2    .0011(r)
.25   .01
.3(r) .01(r)
.5    .1
```

Values that are easy to represent in base 10 are not always even finitely representable in base 2.  [The `Decimal` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) exists specifically to fill the need of maintaining decimal precision for floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is the string convertion. In the end, I am converting everything to strings to format everything for POSTGRESQL. If i do

```
values = [repr(vaue) for value in values]
```

the uploaded value is correct.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You'll still have problems running calculations with extracted values given what you described as "weird values" in the comments to @Shane's answer.  You're also going to take a performance hit with all the string conversions.

Comment: Hm...the string conversion is done quite fast (the table is populated in 10 seconds, having >40000 lines and including some calculations). On the other hand, you're right about the the calculations afterwards...looks like I wont scape using the "Decimal" module!